# READ format in FORTRAN

Tags: io, fortran

I am trying to read a vector components from an external file:

imposed.dat (just one line, numbers separated by commas):

```
0.0585560952144390,0.121244222730239,0.148358440672875,0.169973557163769,0.188894991200908,0.6376108145572
```

I can't provide a MWE as the code is large, but this is a piece of it:

```
OPEN (91,file= 'imposed.dat',form='formatted',status='old') 
read(91,*) CU1P(:)
write(*,*) 'read once imposed profile...'
DO J=2,5
  write(*,*) 'printf CU1P(J) ',CU1P(J)
END DO
```

where CU1P is defined as

```
  REAL*8 CU1P(0:129)
```

The error I get is

```
forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read, unit 91, file /data/forcing/imposed.dat
```

I have read files like this in the past, so I don't know what's going on, did I miss anything?

Comment: Aren't you trying to read 130 items from a file with 6?  Can you please expand on what you expect the result to be?

Comment: I see your point but doesn't FORTRAN allocate the input data up to the 6th component? Regardless of the size of the defined variable (I mean, it's larger)

Comment: @Andrea, no.  Fortran (which is the correct spelling of the name of the language) will try to read 130 numbers from imposed.dat.  If you only need 6 numbers or only have 6 numbers then use `read(91,*) CU1P(0:5)`

Comment: Alright, thank you all!

Comment: Steve, consider writing a proper answer, so OP can accept it.